# I can't identify this kanji

Tags: kanji

I'd like to know what the second kanji stands for. I've searched and searched, and still I couldn't find what kanji it is.

[image]

Answer (score 4):

This is simply the character 棲; the compound is 同棲{どうせい} "to cohabit, stay under one roof", usually referring to living with a de facto partner.